# So how do you re-download movies now?

Tags: itunes, icloud

In the iPad 3 keynote, they mentioned that you are now (or will be?) able to redownload movies just like music and TV shows.

However, if I go to my iPad I still only see Music and TV Shows in the redownload section.

Has anyone actually tried this yet?   It's a Disney movie so it should qualify (I know some Fox movies or something aren't allowed to do this yet)

Is this an upcoming feature or is this supposed to be available today?

Also, I'm in Canada if that makes a difference... thanks.

**UPDATED WITH ANSWER:

Appears to be US only at the moment :(**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a difference in Canada, but here in the US if you select the Purchased tab in iTunes, it now appears to be split into 3 sections. Music, Movies and TV Shows.

This more apparent on the iPhone. On the iPad in the upper left corner is a tab indicating "View: Music". If you tap it you can change to Movies or TV Shows.

Comment: As of right now, with a Canadian iTunes account and running iOS 5.1, I've only got Music and TV Shows options under the Purchased tab in iTunes (I've never downloaded any movies *or* TV, so I assume this isn't specific to my purchasing history). Hopefully Movies will become available here soon if in fact they aren't. :)

Comment: @djacobson - I've downloaded Movies and see them under this tab. I've never downloaded TV Shows, but the tab is still there and selecting it shows "No purchased items". In your case, I assume they might have made this US only to start.

Comment: Yep, appears to be US only.  Bummer

Comment: Hopefully you'll get it soon.